# A detail in the proof of Schur's lemma: the closures of the $\ker$ and $\operatorname{img}$ of the intertwiner.

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, mathematical-physics, unbounded-operators

Consider two irreducibles of a topological group $G$, acting in respective Hilbert spaces $\,\mathbb V\,$ and $\,{\mathbb{V}}^{\,\prime}\,$.

Schur's lemma says:

An intertwiner $\,M\,:\; {\mathbb{V}}\longrightarrow{\mathbb{V}}^{\,\prime}\,$ of two irreducibles of a group is either zero or isomorphism.

To prove it, we first show that both $\,{\operatorname{img}} \,M\,$ and $\,{\ker} \,M\,$ are invariant subspaces.  Then two observations are made.

**Observation 1.** For the invariance of $\,{\operatorname{img}} \,M\,$ to agree with the irreducibility, $\,{\operatorname{img}} \,M\,$ must coincide either with the space $\,{\mathbb{V}}^{\,\prime}\,$ or with its zero vector $\,\vec{0}^{\,\prime}\,$.

**Observation 2.** For the invariance of $\,{\ker} \,M\,$ to agree with the irreducibility, $\,{\ker} \,M\,$ must coincide either with the space $\mathbb V$ or with its zero vector $\,\vec{0}\,$.

Summing up these observations, we conclude that $M$ is either zero or bijective and therefore invertible.

Now, my **question**. Is it really true that $\,{\operatorname{img}} \,M\,$ itself must coincide either with $\,{\mathbb{V}}^{\,\prime}\,$ or $\,\vec{0}^{\,\prime}\,$? $\;$Or is it sooner the *closure* of $\,{\operatorname{img}} \,M\,$ that must satisfy this requirement?  I am enquiring, because a representation is always defined in a Hilbert space or in a *closed* subspace thereof.

The same question about $\,{\ker} \,M\,$. Should we prove that it is actually its *closure* that is invariant?

If it is the closures of $\,{\operatorname{img}}\, M\,$ and $\,{\ker}\, M\,$ whose invariance needs to be proven, do we need to impose additional requirements on the representations and/or on the intertwiner $\,M\,$? (say, boundedness?)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124312/discussion-on-question-by-michael-1812-a-detail-in-the-proof-of-schurs-lemma-t).

Comment: For kernel you can just use `\ker`. For image `\operatorname{img}` is nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In what follows, I will summarize the main points from the discussion in the comments to the OP above, and then proceed with a qualified answer.

There are two different notions of irreducibility for a representation $U$ of a group $G$ in a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$:

- $U$ is said to be *algebraically irreducible* if there are no nontrivial, proper $U(G)$-invariant subspaces: if $\mathscr{W}\subset\mathscr{H}$ is a subspace such that $U(g)\mathscr{W}\subset\mathscr{W}$ for all $g\in G$, then $\mathscr{W}=\{0\}$ or $\mathscr{W}=\mathscr{H}$.
- $U$ is said to be *topologically irreducible* if there are no nontrivial, proper *closed* $U(G)$-invariant subspaces: if $\mathscr{W}\subset\mathscr{H}$ is a *closed* subspace such that $U(g)\mathscr{W}\subset\mathscr{W}$ for all $g\in G$, then $\mathscr{W}=\{0\}$ or $\mathscr{W}=\mathscr{H}$.

Recall that a subspace of a Hilbert space is complete (hence, a Hilbert space itself when endowed with the scalar product of the ambient space) if and only if it is closed. Obviously, algebraic irreducibility of $U$ only depends on the vector space structure of $\mathscr{H}$ (the scalar product and the topology induced by it are irrelevant) and entails topological irreducibility, whereas the converse is not always true.

If $U$ is algebraically irreducible, then Schur's lemma is just a statement on linear algebra and is proven exactly as you wrote above - let us review the argument in a suitable form for later use. If $U_i$ are representations of $G$ in respective Hilbert spaces $\mathscr{H}_i$, $i=1,2$ and $T:\mathscr{H}_1\rightarrow\mathscr{H}_2$ is a linear map such that $TU_1(g)=U_2(g)T$ for all $g\in G$ (i.e. $T$ is an *intertwiner* of $U_1$ with $U_2$), then $U_1(G)\ker(T)\subset\ker(T)$ and $U_2(G)\mathrm{ran}(T)\subset\mathrm{ran}(T)$, where $\ker(T)=T^{-1}(0)=T^{-1}(\{0\})\subset\mathscr{H}_1$ is the kernel of $T$ and $\mathrm{ran}(T)=T(\mathscr{H}_1)\subset\mathscr{H}_2$ is the image (range) of $T$, hence $\ker(T)$ and $\mathrm{ran}(T)$ are $U(G)$-invariant subspaces. If $U_1,U_2$ are (algebraically) irreducible, this entails that $\ker(T)=\{0\}$ or $\mathscr{H}_1$ and $\mathrm{ran}(T)=\{0\}$ or $\mathscr{H}_2$, noting that $\ker(T)=\mathscr{H}_1$ and $\mathscr{ran}(T)=\{0\}$ are equivalent statements. This entails that either:

- $T=0$ (which is equivalent to *either* $\ker(T)=\mathscr{H}_1$ or $\mathscr{ran}(T)=\{0\}$ ), or
- $T$ is bijective (which is equivalent to *both* $\ker(T)=\{0\}$ and $\mathscr{ran}(T)=\mathscr{H}_2$).

In the case that $U_1,U_2$ are *topologically* irreducible representations of $G$, one needs further hypotheses to proceed, unless $\mathscr{H}_1,\mathscr{H}_2$ are finite dimensional (in which case both notions of irreducibility are equivalent, for then any subspace is closed). For topologically irreducible representations, it is customary to require the following:

1. $G$ is a *topological* group (i.e. $G$ is endowed with a topology such that the product $G\times G\ni(g,h)\mapsto gh\in G$ and the inversion $G\ni g\mapsto g^{-1}\in G$ are continuous maps - equivalently, such a topology makes the map $G\times G\ni (g,h)\mapsto gh^{-1}\in G$ continuous);
2. $U_i(g)$ is a *bounded* (equivalently, continuous) linear operator in $\mathscr{H}_i$, $i=1,2$;
3. $U_i$ is *continuous* e.g. with respect to the strong operator topology in $\mathfrak{B}(\mathscr{H}_i)=$ C*-algebra of bounded linear operators in $\mathscr{H}_i$, $i=1,2$;
4. An intertwiner $T:\mathscr{H}_1\rightarrow\mathscr{H}_2$ of $U_1$ with $U_2$ is assumed to be a *bounded* (equivalently, continuous) linear map.

A few comments about assumptions 1.-4. are in order. For the Schur lemma to hold, one does not really need 1. or 3., but one does need 4. and something stronger than 2. - more precisely, we need that $U_i(g)$ is *unitary* for all $g\in G$, $i=1,2$ (the reason why will become clear shortly). If $G$ is Hausdorff and *compact* one can get away with 1.-4. without requiring unitarity of $U_i$ a priori, for the Haar probability measure on $G$ then allows one to obtain from the scalar product on $\mathscr{H}_i$ a new scalar product w.r.t. which $U_i(g)$ is unitary for all $g\in G$ (Weyl's unitary trick). Now we are ready to state the appropriate topological version of Schur's lemma:

> **Lemma:** Let $U_i:G\rightarrow\mathfrak{B}(\mathscr{H}_i)$ be a topologically irreducible unitary representation of the topological group $G$ in the Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}_i$, $i=1,2$. Then any bounded intertwiner $T\in\mathfrak{B}(\mathscr{H}_1,\mathscr{H}_2)$ of $U_1$ with $U_2$ is either zero or a topological isomorphism.

Notice that the boundedness of $T$ is used to ensure not only that $T$ is everywhere defined but also that the intertwining relation makes sense everywhere. Moreover, in this case $\ker(T)$ is necessarily closed but $\mathrm{ran}(T)$ *not necessarily so* if $\mathscr{H}_1$ and $\mathscr{H}_2$ are infinite dimensional, so the proof of the Lemma (which is essentially the same as the [one provided in MO by Johannes Ebert](https://mathoverflow.net/a/392797/11211)) will necessarily be more involved. For the sake of readability for the math.SE audience, I am being a bit verbose here with (most of) the details since the MO answer is quite short.

**Proof of Lemma:** If $TU_1(g)=U_2(g)T$, then taking adjoints yields $$U_1(g)^*T^*=U_1(g^{-1})T^*=T^*U_2(g)^*=T^*U_2(g^{-1})\ ,$$ where the first and last identities follow from the fact that $U_1,U_2$ are unitary. This implies that if $T$ is a bounded intertwiner of $U_1$ with $U_2$, then $T^*$ is an intertwiner of $U_2$ with $U_1$ (in that order). Hence we conclude that $$T^*TU_1(g)=T^*U_2(g)T=U_1(g)T^*T$$ for all $g\in G$, that is, $T^*T$ is a bounded intertwiner of $U_1$ with itself, that is, $T^*T$ *commutes with* $U_1(g)$ for all $g\in G$. Since $T^*T$ is *self-adjoint*, we can apply the *spectral theorem*: the *spectrum* $$\sigma(T^*T)=\{\lambda\in\mathbb{C}\mid T^*T-\lambda\mathbf{1}\text{ is not invertible}\}$$ of $T^*T$ is a *nonvoid* closed (and bounded, since $T^*T$ is bounded) subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (even if $T^*T$ has *no* eigenvalues!), and there is a Borel measure $P$ on $\mathbb{R}$ supported in $\sigma(T^*T)$ taking values in the orthogonal projections on $\mathscr{H}_1$ such that $T^*T$ admits the *spectral integral representation* $$T^*T=\int_{\sigma(T^*T)}\lambda dP(\lambda)\ .$$ It turns out that $U_1(g)$ must then commute with the spectral projection $P(A)$ of $T^*T$ for every Borel subset $A\subset\mathbb{R}$ and for all $g\in G$.

To see this, recall how spectral projections are obtained - firstly, it is clear that any polynomial in $T^*T$ commutes with $U_1(g)$. By the Stone-Weierstrass theorem applied to any closed interval containing $\sigma(T^*T)$, one sees that any continuous function of $T^*T$ commutes with $U_1(g)$. Finally, for every open interval $A$ of $\mathbb{R}$ we have by the monotone and dominated convergence theorems, and the fact that the characteristic function of $A$ is the pointwise limit of an increasing sequence of continuous functions, that $U_1(g)$ commutes with $P(A)$. This extends to any other Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$ by approximation.

Notice now that every orthogonal projection $P$ is bounded, hence continuous and therefore with a *closed kernel*, and also has a *closed range* (for $\mathrm{ran}(P)=\ker(\mathbf{1}-P)$) - hence $\ker(P(A))$ and $\mathrm{ran}(P(A))$ are *closed* $U(G)$-invariant subspaces for every Borel subset $A\subset\mathbb{R}$. Like in the proof of the original (algebraic) version of Schur's lemma, this entails that $P(A)$ ie either zero or an isomorphism - in the latter case we must have $P(A)=\mathbf{1}=P(\sigma(T^*T))$, for this is the only nonzero orthogonal projection with that property. Since this holds for every Borel subset $A\subset\mathbb{R}$, $T^*T$ must be a (possibly zero) scalar multiple of the identity in $\mathscr{H}_1$. Likewise, we conclude that $TT^*$ is a bounded self-adjoint intertwiner of $U_2$ with itself and, by the same argument as above, $TT^*$ must be a (possibly zero) scalar multiple of the identity in $\mathscr{H}_2$. Since $$\langle\psi,T^*T\psi\rangle=\|T\psi\|^2\geq 0\ ,\, \langle\phi,TT^*\phi\rangle=\|T^*\phi\|^2\geq 0\ ,\quad\psi\in\mathscr{H}_1\ ,\,\phi\in\mathscr{H}_2\ ,$$ we must have $T^*T=\lambda\mathbf{1}$ and $TT^*=\mu\mathbf{1}$ for some $\lambda,\mu\geq 0$. The same identities above imply that if either $\lambda=0$ or $\mu=0$ then $T=0$, so let us assume that $\lambda,\mu>0$. In that case, $T$ must be bijective, for then $\ker(T)\subset\ker(T^*T)=\{0\}$ and $\mathrm{ran}(T)\supset\mathrm{ran}(TT^*)=\mathscr{H}_2$. By the open mapping theorem, $T^{-1}$ must then be continuous as well. $\Box$

The spectral theorem is precisely what allows us to circumvent the fact that $T$ may not have closed range if $\mathscr{H}_1$ and $\mathscr{H}_2$ are infinite dimensional (of course, it turns out that $T$ does have closed range if $U_1$ and $U_2$ are topologically irreducible, but we do not know that a priori). The proof of the Lemma also implies that, given a (bounded) intertwiner $T\in\mathfrak{B}(\mathscr{H})$ of a topologically irreducible representation $U$ of $G$ by bounded linear operators on a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$ with itself, we have that if $T$ has a spectral integral representation then $T$ must be a (possibly zero) scalar multiple of the identity (here unitarity of $U$ is not needed, for we do not need to deal with $T^*$ in this case). This is the case if:

- $\mathscr{H}$ complex: $T^*T=TT^*$ (i.e. $T$ is *normal*);
- $\mathscr{H}$ real: $T=T^*$ (i.e. $T$ is self-adjoint).

I conclude with a small aside: the counterexample you [displayed in your own MO answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/336559/dixmiers-lemma-as-a-generalisation-of-schurs-first-lemma/341443#341443) does not really apply to *Hilbert space* representations of $G$, for the vector space $\mathbb{C}(x)$ of all rational functions of one variable $x$ with complex coefficients is not a Hilbert space. More precisely, no scalar product is provided, let alone one that makes $\mathbb{C}(x)$ complete.

Comment: Many thanks for this detailed and enlightening answer. Can you please tell me why exactly the space $\mathbb{C}(x)$ is not Hilbert? Is it not complete?

Comment: One more silly question. Why do you say "there are no nontrivial, proper U(G)-invariant subspaces..."? I used to think that *nontrivial* means *not equal to $\vec 0$*, while *proper* means *neither $\vec 0$ nor ${\mathscr{H}}$*. So, if my understanding is right, *proper* warrants *nontrivial*. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: One more technicality. When saying that a dot product generates a topology, you probably imply that a dot product naturally generates a norm -- which in its turn naturally generates a topology. Is my reading of your words correct?

Comment: And one more. You start out with the distinction between the *algebraic* irreducibility and *topological* irreducibility. Is my understanding correct that, in a similar way, we should distinguish between the two kinds of reducibility? - so a rep is algebraically reducible if it possesses a proper invariant subspace, and topologically reducible if that subspace is closed?

Comment: 1.) First of all, what is the scalar product on $C(x)$? Then you ask whether this scalar product generates a vector space topology w.r.t. which $C(x)$ is complete, for (unlike in finite dimensions) not all scalar products (maybe none) will have this property.

Comment: 2.) The terminology on this is admitedly not uniform in the literature. Sometimes you will see people using just "nontrivial" instead of "proper". My rationale indeed is the following: "nontrivial" refers to the fact that $\{0\}$ is usually called the *trivial* subspace, whereas "proper" refers to the inclusion (i.e. the subspace inclusion map is not the identity). Both are pretty standard outside representation theory.

Comment: 3.) Indeed you are correct. The Hilbert space topology is induced by the norm associated to the scalar product.

Comment: 4.) Yes, both kinds of reducibility should be distinguished generally, for they are usually not the same in infinite dimensions. The difference between both is the one you pointed. As a rule, when dealing with reps of topological groups in a Hilbert space, the topological notion of (ir)reducibility tends to be more useful.

Comment: Thank you, Pedro. So, regarding item (2), your meaning of *proper* excludes the ambient space, but does not exclude $\{\vec 0\}$, correct? And therefore you have to say "nontrivial proper"?

Comment: @Michael_1812 yes, that's my reasoning behind it.

Comment: Dear Pedro, many thanks for your time and help. Learned a lot from you.

Comment: Dear Pedro, could you please also prove that a subspace of a Hilbert space is complete iff it is closed, or provide a reference where the proof could be looked up? Thank you!!

Comment: @Michael_1812 this is standard - a Cauchy sequence in a subspace of a Hilbert space is also a Cauchy sequence in the ambient space, hence it converges to a vector in the latter since the ambient space is complete. Moreover, any limit of a sequence of vectors in a subspace of a Hilbert space lies in the closure of the former. Exercise: complete the details ;-)

Comment: The above shows closed $\Rightarrow$ complete. To show the converse statement, take any point in the closure of the subspace - one can then find a sequence of vectors in that subspace converging to it. Being convergent, such a sequence is Cauchy; since the subspace is assumed complete, the limit also belongs to the subspace, hence the latter coincides with its closure.

Comment: Pedro, this is very helpful, really. Many thanks!!

Comment: Dear Pedro, I am trying to grasp why the completeness yields closedness. We take any point $p$ in the closure of the subspace and find in that subspace a sequence converging to $p$.  If $p$ happens to reside in the subspace, we are done. If $p$ is a limit point, there is (another) point of the subset within an arbitrary neighbourhood thereof. So, to build a converging sequence, consider circles of radii $r_n\longrightarrow 0$.  A circle of $r=r_1$ contains a point $p_1$. Then we take a circle of the radius $r_2 < d(p,\,p_1)$, to find a closer point $p_2\neq p_1$. Etc...  Is my method correct?

Comment: Dear Pedro, one more kind resuest, if I may. Could you kimndly provide a reference on this material? Preferably, some simple text available to a physicist.

Comment: Strictly speaking, your reasoning is correct, but it's somewhat cleaner to pick a more explicit, strictly decreasing sequence of radii $r_n$ - e.g. $r_n=2^{-n}$ Since then $p_n$ will be contained in the open ball $B_{r_n}(p)\subset B_{r_N}(p)$ for all $n\geq N$, it follows from the triangle inequality that $d(p_n,p_m)\leq d(p_n,p)+d(p_m,p)\leq 2r_N=2^{1-N}$ for all $n,m\geq N$ and therefore $(p_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: Wow. That' kinda elegant. Thank you!

Comment: Any introductory book on functional analysis will do. Two books which are particularly agreeable to physicists are E. Kreyszig's "Introduction to Functional Analysis" and M. Reed and B. Simon's "Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics I - Functional Analysis".

Comment: Thank you, Pedro, for your time and help! Will look up these texts.

Comment: Dear Pedro, I guess you could be the one capable of commenting on this question, if interested:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4260528/complete-reducibility-in-linear-algebra-and-in-topology